# Can I pull the graph schema programmatically in Memgraph?

Tags: memgraphdb

In Memgraph Lab there is an option view and generate Graph schema. This view is nice when I need to see the schema, but can I somehow pull the data that is behind it? Maybe using some API.

[image: Graph scheme in Memgraph Lab]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to get graph schema:

- [Schema procedure from meta util](https://memgraph.com/docs/advanced-algorithms/available-algorithms/meta_util#schema)
- [Raw schema procedure from llm util](https://memgraph.com/docs/advanced-algorithms/available-algorithms/llm_util#schema)
- [Schema procedures](https://memgraph.com/docs/querying/functions#schema) - probably the most performant one since it's a function built-in inside Memgraph